# Validate that csv has comma separated values in Bash

Tags: bash, csv, validation

Hi I have the following csv file:

- file1.csv:

```
1,2,3
asjkhfajsdkfasdj,2,iasuhdsg;ghasdgjklh
<>A<SF@!*AFSL<,ahsodgasdklgjaskd2152351235,12
hello,world,!
```

I want to validate that the above csv file has the following structure (3 values (any character) separated by 2 commas):

```
value1,value2,value3
```

and not any of the following patterns:

```
value1
value1,
value1,value2
value1,value2,
value1,value2,value3,
value1,value2,value3,value4
```

I tried using this command ([see link here](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/25477-how-validate-csv-file.html)):

```
CSVcnt=`awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}END{print NF}' $csv_file`
echo "CSVcnt = $CSVcnt"
```

The above command will return 3 which is correct.

---

But let's consider the following scenario using the following:

- file2.csv

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

Will return 3 which is ***incorrect***

---

- file3.csv

```
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Will return 10 which is ***correct***

---

- file4.csv

```
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4
```

Will return 4 which is ***incorrect***

So, it looks like the `awk` command that I'm using is based on last line only. Can you please suggest if there is a way to use the awk command to return the maximum number found in the entire file?
Please note, I prefer not to use REGEX and prefer not to use a for-loop if possible. (each csv will have from 10K to 40K lines)

Comment: can the values contain commas? if the answer is 'yes' then update the question to include a couple rows with such

Comment: must all 3 values be non-empty/non-blank? or is `,,value3` acceptable as a valid tuple?

Comment: no, don't worry about that one. The data should never contain comma, just the delimeters only will be comma

Comment: `,,value3` dont worry about that one either. will check it later in the code

Comment: How is file3 correct returning 10?  When the header has 3 values.  The point of CSV is to have subsequent rows to match match the header?

Comment: there is no header

Comment: please update the question to show the expected output for each set of sample inputs; do you want to show the lines that match? do you want to show a count of the lines that match? what about a count of the lines that don't match? do you need a 'yes' or 'no' to signify the entire file matches or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get the maximum value of `NF` then you can do this:

```bash
awk -F ',' 'NF > maxNF {maxNF = NF} END {print maxNF+0}' file.csv
```

Comment: Looks to be okay. still doing some testing, will let you know shortly

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou this will (erroneously) report `3` for `value1,value2,`; if the last field cannot be empty/blank, but can be white space, then: `awk -F',' 'NF>maxNF && $(NF)!="" {maxNF=NF} END {print maxNF}' file.csv`

Comment: @markp-fuso That's right, this solution doesn't check the content of the fields at all

Comment: as said in previous comment. i don't care if value is empty or only spaces. only care if entire csv have no more than 2 separators (3 values even if empty `,,`)

Comment: just checked with 3K records. looks to be working as fine, accepting this as final answer Thanks @Fravadona
short and simple

Comment: Is it possible to get minimum value as well? I tried this `awk -F ',' 'NF < minNF {minNF = NF} END {print minNF+0}' file.csv` but is returning 0

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou you can: `awk -F ',' 'NF > 0 && (NF < minNF || !defined ) {minNF = NF; defined = 1} END {print minNF+0}'` file.csv`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the fields

```
awk -F, '{a[NF]++} END {for (e in a) {print e ":" a[e]}}' file.csv
```

produces something like

```
3:2
4:1
10:1
```

for your example

```
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't worry about quoted fields (which can contain newlines as well as literal commas which are not field separators), maybe try a two-pass solution.

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS=":" }
  NR==FNR { ++n[NF]; next }
  FNR == 1 { for(k in n) if (n[k] > m) { m=n[k]; f=k } }
  NF != k { print FILENAME, FNR, $0 }' file.csv file.csv
```

to print all the lines which have a different number of fields than the "normal" number (which is simply determined by establishing the count which is true for the largest number of lines in the file).

If you also want to print lines where the last field is empty, you can add

```
  (!$NF) ||
```

before the last condition.

A proper solution is hard to do in Awk alone, but pretty straightforward with Python; the `csv` module in the standard library copes with several dialects of CSV and copes correctly with quoted fields etc.